# RavenDB: The best way to wait for non-stale index first then query stale index if timeout

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I'm using Ravendb 2.5. I have the situation that I need wait for none-stale index first, and if it's timeout after 15 seconds, query the stale index rather than throw a timeout exception. Here is my code.

```
RavenQueryStatistics stats;
var result = queryable.Statistics(out stats).Take(maxPageSize).ToList();
if (stats.IsStale)
{
    try
    {
        return queryable.Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15))).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return result;
    }
}
else
{
    return result;
}
```

I need add extension method to make the above code work for all the queries, for example:
    public static List ToList(this IRavenQueryable queryable)

I may also need add extension method to overwrite: .All(), .Any(), .Contains(), .Count(), .ToList(), .ToArray(), .ToDictionary(), .First(), .FirstOrDefault(), .Single(), .SingleOrDefault(), .Last(), .LastOrDefault(), etc.

I wonder if there is any other better solution for this. What's the best practice?

Does ravendb has an AOP cut point that when timeout exception throws, we can do something to change the query the stable index and return stale results?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements, I would prefer to have this as two separate calls from the end-user client. First issue a query without waiting for non-stale results, show the query results immediatly to the end-user. If the results are stale then make that visible to the end-user, and make a second query to the server where you wait for non-stale results.

That way the end-user will always get something to see quickly without having to wait potentially 15 seconds even for stale results.

Answer (score 0):

You may force the document store to always wait for the last write, then you could use queries without customize instructions

```
documentStore.Conventions.DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites;
```

Note: If the index is very busy or you write something to DB and query relative data immediately, using async instead of timeout will be better.

```
//deal with very busy index
using (var session = documentStore.OpenAsyncSession())
{      
     var result = await session.Query<...>()
                   .Where(x => ...)
                   .ToListAsync();
}
//write then read
using (var session = documentStore.OpenAsyncSession())
{    
     await session.StoreAsync(entity);
     await session.SaveChangesAsync();  
     //query relative data of entity
     var result = await session.Query<...>()
                   .Where(x => ...)
                   .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: I used ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites before and it has performance issue and return timeout exception after 15 seconds, so I want to use a better way. That's why I use the new query solution that I wait for none-stale index first, and if it's timeout after 15 seconds, query the stale index rather than throw a timeout exception.

Comment: any chance you have an update in how to do it with the current version? v5.4